# Заголовок Content-Length для передачи JSON

Tags: json, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Очень часто в чужом коде и примерах я вижу такой код:

```
var userData = new UserInfo(login, pass);
            var userData = JSON.stringify(userData);
            request.onreadystatechange = asincComplete;

            request.open("POST", "user_auth.php", true);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", userData.length);
            request.send(userData);
```

У меня след. вопрос:
Почему заголовком Content-Length передают длину строки в симовлах (свойство length), тогда как должна быть указана длина в байтах? Я понимаю, что выше приведенный код справедлив только для латинских символов, но не для остальных символов юникода.

**Каким способом вы кодируете json данные? И каким способом их декодируете на сервере (например, на php)?**

Спасибо.

Comment: Круто. Подпишусь)

Потыкал в консоль - JS реально выдает "Ф".length == 1. По идее, мой сервер такой запрос должен бы отклонить (недопринять), но если это работает - очень странно.

Comment: Все сервера это прощают, но полагаться на это не здорово

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...
>
> 5.Terminate these steps if header is a case-insensitive match for one of the following headers:
>
> Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Connection, **Content-Length**, Cookie, Cookie2, Date, DNT, Expect, Host, Keep-Alive, Origin, Referer, TE, Trailer, Transfer-Encoding, Upgrade, User-Agent, Via
>
> … or if the start of header is a case-insensitive match for Proxy- or  Sec- (including when header is just Proxy- or Sec-).
>
> ...

[отсюда](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method)

Это означает, что далеко не все заголовки для запроса можно установить, используя `XMLHttpRequest`. Firefox 23.0 молча отбрасывает такие попытки, Chrome извещает в консоли вот так: `Refused to set unsafe header`, про остальные браузеры ничего сказать не могу. Конкретно `Content-Length` в вышеупомянутом списке с 2006 года, так что код либо очень старый, либо некачественный.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно выставлять зголов length, это сделает сам браузер:

```
function sendJson(url, jsonData, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.onload = function (){ callback(xhr) };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
}

sendJson('/save/', { "foo": "bar" }, function (xhr){
    console.log(xhr);
});
```

Comment: Вопрос-то не в этом) Вопрос в том, почему работает и зачем вообще тогда нужен заголовок Content-Length, если его явно неверное указание ничего не ломает?

Comment: @KaZaца — верно [ответил][1].
[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/243906/javascript-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-content-length-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-json#244318